# Python 3.4 Dice Rolling Simulator Code Error

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.4

So I have my code here for a dice rolling simulator game that I am creating using PyDev in Eclipse Neon Python 3.4. Where you guess a number and a number from 1-6 will randomly generate and if you get the number right, you move on, etc.

```
guess1 = input("Enter your first guess as to which side the dice will roll on (1-6): ")

import random
dice_side = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']

game = print(random.choice(dice_side))

if guess1 == game: 
    print("Congrats that's the correct guess!")
else:
    print("That's the wrong guess!")
```

I tested out the code and everytime I put in a number, the console always print "That's the wrong guess!". Even when the number I guess matched the generated number. I can't quite figure out what's wrong with this. I was thinking maybe I should use a *while* loop instead. However, I wanted to know if I can do it this way and what's wrong with this particular code. I am new to Python so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about what `print` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print()` returns `None`. If you print `game` after that line you will see it's value. To fix:

```
game = random.choice(dice_side)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand why your game isn't working you should try to understand first what's wrong with this line `game = print(random.choice(dice_side))`. Here's a modified version of your game which will give you some clues, try to run it and understand it, then just review your script:

```
import random

dice_side = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

game = random.choice(dice_side)
print("Dice has been rolled... :D {0}".format(game))
guess = -1
number_attempts = 0

while True:
    guess = raw_input("Which side the dice has rolled on (1-6): ")
    number_attempts += 1

    if guess == game:
        print("Congrats that's the correct guess! You've tried {0} times".format(
            number_attempts))
        break

    print("That's the wrong guess!")
```

One advice, once you've discovered why isn't working, just try to add more and more new features till your game becomes really addictive and interesting... but the most important, just have fun :)